# Why are standardized tests (university finals, SAT, ACT, IB, etc...) normally distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

As the title states, why do we observe a normal distribution for these exams? Is it just because scores are likely a sum of random variables?

A rigorous or semi-rigorous answer would be pretty nice perhaps with some key pieces of intuition or starting points for light research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't exactly normally distributed. After all, attaining negative values is possible with a normally distributed random variable, but attaining a negative test score is (hopefully!) impossible. Normal random variables also have no upper bound, while all exams have a maximum amount of marks.

But standardized test scores do *approximate* a normal distribution. This is because these tests often ask many separate questions that are not related to each other. In addition, most questions do not require that you've answered the previous question correctly. And in general, these exams are neither too easy nor too difficult. These conditions do lend to the approximation of a normal distribution.

Comment: Hmm interesting! Can you explain further about:

"This is because these tests often ask many separate questions that are not related to each other. In addition, most questions do not require that you've answered the previous question correctly. And in general, these exams are neither too easy nor too difficult."

Comment: Sure! Most standardized tests are comprised of a large multiple choice section often with dozens of small, separate questions. If questions were chained (for example, you need the answer from Q1 to answer Q2, and you need the answer from Q2 to answer Q3, etc), then you would not expect scores to be normally distributed; you'd have a few perfect or near-perfect scores, and many low scores (from students who made an error along the way). The discrete nature of standardized test question mitigates this.

Comment: On top of this, if most students do not know all the answers and then guess some or all of the unknown ones in a multiple choice test, then you get binomial distribution smoothing on top of the actual distribution of knowledge, and this can make the combined distribution look more bell shaped.

Comment: This makes sense, but how exactly in terms of the CLT would having separate questions be analogous to adding RVs or a sampling distribution?

Comment: Also how do they manage to set the mean/sd?